# Form preventDefault then activate again not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a little form in my modal which looks like this:

```
    <form name="form" action="" method="post">
          <div class="modal-body">
              <input type="text" name="edited_id" value="" id="edited_id" class="hidden"/>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="edited_name" class="form-control" id="edit_name" value="">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="edited_email" class="form-control" id="edit_email" value="">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <input type="submit" name="edit_submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Edit user"/>
          </div>
      </form>
```

and I want to prevent the form to submit if the user enters an email that it is already in my database. I have the following script:

```
$("#check_email").click(function() {
    var email = $(this).parent().siblings().find("#email").val();
    var that = $(this);
    $(this).parent().parent().submit(function( event ) {
        $.get("php/verify_email.php", {email: email}, function(data){
            if(data === "")
            {
                that.parent().parent().unbind('submit').submit();
            }
            else {
                alert(data);
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is that if I put the `even.preventDefault()` in that else condition, the `$.get()` seems to not trigger, because I guess that the form submits faster. Otherwise if I put the `event.preventDefault()` right after the `.submit(function( event ) {` then I can't unbind the submit to work after the user changes the email.

What I am doing wrong?

P.S.

My php file looks like this:

```
<?php
include "connect.php";

if(isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email'])){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$_GET['email']."';";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
        echo "The email is already in our database. Please try another one!";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: `preventDefault()` is not to be used in the case of a data mis-match as the form will still submit normally. You should code in such a way that no duplicate information is entered into the database.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I am learning now the AJAX and PHP so... easier said then done. :)

Comment: Check,

    $("#check_email").click(function(event) {});
   
    event.preventDefault();

Comment: My guess is data is not empty. `console.log(escape(data));`

Answer (score 1):

I understand you would like to avoid form sending if email is already used.

**At first**, where is your magic button to do this :D ?
I added button in [example](http://jsfiddle.net/n0w3v6cj/).
You must be sure that your "`this`" is element you want, creating structure like `.parent().parent().parent()` everywhere is stupid - one change and everything not work.

**Next thing** to avoid form submit you must `return false;` inside submit function, `preventDefault()` work with `<a>` or other events like `click`

**And next..** if you send ajax your callback function can back to your browser  after your submit click.
For example *`checkClick -> sendAjax -> submitClick -> ajaxBack`*

**And next** :D - PHP: Your form have `method="post"` but server use $_GET
So.. if you send `post` you must use $_POST if `get` than $_GET

This time you used $.get so i dont know your ajax configuration but this can cause errors.

Here is some code but im sure this is not final implementation you want, but it should help :)
sorry for english btw.

html:

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
      <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="text" name="edited_id" value="" id="edited_id" class="hidden"/>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="edited_name" class="form-control" id="edit_name" value="">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="edited_email" class="form-control" id="edit_email" value=""> <button type="button" id="check_email" data-dismiss="modal">check</button>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <input type="submit" name="edit_submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Edit user"/>
      </div>
  </form>
```

javascript:

```
$("#check_email").click(function() {
    var email = $(this).parent().find("#email").val();
    var that = $(this);
        alert(email);
    console.log($(this).parent().parent().parent())
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().submit(function( event ) {
        $.get("php/verify_email.php", {email: email}, function(data){
            if(data === "")
            {
                that.parent().parent().unbind('submit').submit();
            }
            else {
                alert(data);
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: 1. I added the wrong form, it is the same with this one but it has an id on the button. 2. Now I can't get my AJAX to work.

Comment: So where is your problem now? Can you edit your question and some code ? Are you sure your php file work ? Maybe your ajax configuration is wrong http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ ?